# Arduino no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, file, variables, arduino, arduino-uno

I have created program for my arduino uno, but I cannot compile it.
Program based on IRemote IRecord example, and SD example.

CODE:

```
void sendCode(int repeat) {
   strcodeValue = String(codeValue);
   char filename[strcodeValue.length()+1];
   strcodeValue.toCharArray(filename, sizeof(filename));

   if (SD.exists(filename)) {   
   File myFile = SD.open(filename);
   if (myFile) {
    while (myFile.available(filename)) {
      codeValue = myFile.read();
    }
    myFile.close();
  }
   }
...
}
```

ERRORS:

```
IRrecord.ino: In function 'void sendCode(int)':
IRrecord.ino:130:37: error: no matching function for call to 'File::available(char [(((sizetype)<anonymous>) + 1)])'
IRrecord.ino:130:37: note: candidate is:
In file included from IRrecord.ino:18:0:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SD\src/SD.h:38:15: note: virtual int File::available()
   virtual int available();
               ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SD\src/SD.h:38:15: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
Error compiling.
```

File name will be read from IR Sensor.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It surely looks like

```
while (myFile.available(filename)) {
```

should read

```
while (myFile.available()) {
```